# Converting com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point to Dto

Tags: mapstruct

Good day everyone.
Stuck into problem with a class having Point as a field I want to turn into DTO field.
My entity and DTO:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class RentPointDto {
    private String id;

    private String pointName;

    private String type;

    private String coordinate;

}
public class RentPoint {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull(message = "Rent point name should'not be null")
    @Column(name = "point_name")
    private String pointName;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private PointType type;

    @Column(name = "coordinate")
    @NotNull(message = "Coordinate of renting point must be specified!")
    private Point coordinate;
```

(Bunch of stuff omitted for brievety)

My Mapper:

```
public interface GenericMapper<S, DTO> {

    DTO toDto(S s);

    S fromDto(DTO dto);

    List <S> listFromDto(List <DTO> dto);

    List <DTO> listToDto(List <S> entities);
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = GeometryConverter.class)
public interface RentPointMapper extends GenericMapper <RentPoint, RentPointDto> {

}
```

and converter class:

```
@Component
public class GeometryConverter {
    public Point unMap(String str) throws ParseException {
        return (Point) new WKTReader().read( str );
    }

    public String map(Point point) {
        return point.toText();
    }
}
```

generated Impl for Mapper:

```
@Autowired
    private GeometryConverter geometryConverter;

    @Override
    public RentPointDto toDto(RentPoint s) {
        if ( s == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        RentPointDto rentPointDto = new RentPointDto();

        if ( s.getId() != null ) {
            rentPointDto.setId( String.valueOf( s.getId() ) );
        }
        rentPointDto.setPointName( s.getPointName() );
        if ( s.getType() != null ) {
            rentPointDto.setType( s.getType().name() );
        }
        rentPointDto.setCoordinate( geometryConverter.map( s.getCoordinate() ) );

        return rentPointDto;
    }

    @Override
    public RentPoint fromDto(RentPointDto dto) {
        if ( dto == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        RentPoint rentPoint = new RentPoint();

        if ( dto.getId() != null ) {
            rentPoint.setId( Long.parseLong( dto.getId() ) );
        }
        rentPoint.setPointName( dto.getPointName() );
        if ( dto.getType() != null ) {
            rentPoint.setType( Enum.valueOf( PointType.class, dto.getType() ) );
        }
        try {
            rentPoint.setCoordinate( geometryConverter.unMap( dto.getCoordinate() ) );
        }
        catch ( ParseException e ) {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }

        return rentPoint;
    }
```

After all, I got:

> java: Can't map property "Point rentPoint.coordinate" to "String
> rentPoint.coordinate". Consider to declare/implement a mapping method:
> "String map(Point value)".

Answer (score 1):

Mybe late, I develop an annotation processor called [beanknife](https://github.com/vipcxj/beanknife) recently, it support generate DTO from any class. You need config by annotation. But you don't need change the original class. This library support configuring on a separate class. Of course you can choose which property you want and which you not need. And you can add new property by the static method in the config class. For your question:

```
@ViewOf(value = RentPoint.class, genName="RentPointDto" includes = {"id", "pointName"})
class ConfigureObj {
    @NewViewProperty("type")
    public static String type(RentPoint source) {
        // convert the source to String
    }
    @NewViewProperty("coordinate")
    public static String coordinate(RentPoint source) {
        // convert the coordinate to Point
    }
}
```

will generate

```
// meta class, you can use it to reference the property name in a safe way.
class RentPointMeta {
    public final String id = "id";
    public final String pointName = "pointName";
    public final String type = "type";
    public final String coordinate = "coordinate";
}

// generated DTO class. The actual one will be more complicate, there are many other method.
public class RentPointDto {
    private String id;
    private String pointName;
    private String type;
    private String coordinate;
    // some getters and setters. no setters by default.
    public static RentPoint read(RentPointDto source) { ... }
    public static List<RentPoint> read(List<RentPointDto> source) { ... }
    // other read methods.
}
```

No reflect, no magic. All the logic are shown in the genreated class source.
This library is primarily designed to generate read-only objects, so there is only the read method, not the write method. (However, setter methods of the dto is supported.) Maybe the next version will add write support

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved after deleting GenericMapper interface

```
public interface GenericMapper<S, DTO> {

    DTO toDto(S s);

    S fromDto(DTO dto);

    List <S> listFromDto(List <DTO> dto);

    List <DTO> listToDto(List <S> entities);
}
```

Since MapStruct doesn't support params in mapper, I'm not able to put annotation @Mapper(uses=..).That leads to missing geometry converter in RentPointMapper .

Comment: I don't follow the reasoning why it shouldn't work. In my opinion this should work. Can you please raise an issue so we can look into it?